# Compiling haskell source as dynamic library

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I'm trying to compile a Haskell source package as a dynamic library to be used with OCaml code. I tried using the `--enable-shared` option with `cabal install` on the .cabal file of the source, I got a `Perhaps you haven't installed the "dyn" libraries for package 'zeromq4-haskell-0.6.5'` error. After a little googling, I realised that the dependencies must also be compiled as dynamic libraries. I downloaded the source package for zeromq and tried installing the zeromq package with the `--enable-shared` option. This time I got a similar error with one of zeromq's dependencies. I tried doing this 4-5 times and get an error with a different dependency at each level.

Am I making a mistake here? How can I get all of the dependencies to install as dynamic libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generally want to have shared libraries, you can permanently enable it in your `.cabal/config`:

```
shared: True
```

However, it will only affect libraries installed after that, so you may want to purge all libraries and start over again.

If this is just a one-shot, you may create a cabal sandbox just for that purpose:

```
cd yourlib
cabal sandbox init
cabal install --enable-shared
```

The result will be in the directory `.cabal-sandbox`.